# Can't access state from within React.Children.map

Tags: reactjs

I can't seem to access `this.state` from within `React.Children.map`.

I'm attempting to create a component that passes `inputDevices` and `outputDevices` to all children, but I am getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'inputDevices' of null

Here is my render function:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            { React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
                React.cloneElement(child, {
                    inputDevices: this.state.inputDevices,
                    outputDevices: this.state.outputDevices
                }))
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

The state is defined in the same class for this test purpose I have defined the following:

```
static state = {
    inputDevices: [
        { id: 'test', name: 'test' },
        { id: 'test1', name: 'test1' }
    ],
    outputDevices: [
        { id: 'test', name: 'test' },
        { id: 'test1', name: 'test1' }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have declared state as a static property which means it's not accessible as instance property with `this`. You can access it with

```
const state = NameOfTheComponent.state;
```

Comment: Oh dear god. Why did I not notice that. I've recently been using `static propTypes` and `static defaultPropTypes` and I stupidly did that to state too. Time for bed.

Comment: FWIW you don't need `const` as I'm defining the state in the class. Removing static was fine. All works good.

Comment: @BugHunterUK haha, resting sometimes does the job ;)